# flung himself off meaning

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

Recently, I found this sentence, and I'm not sure the correct meaning of it. Unfortunately, I have neither context nor remember where it came from. Here's the phrase:

> He grinned at me and flung himself off.

And the question is: *what **flung himself off** mean?*

Thank you.

Comment: Without context, it is difficult to know.

Comment: It could mean that he jumped.

Comment: Or possibly that he left abruptly - but without context, impossible to say.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to be sure without context but I would interpret this as "jumped off" - as from a rooftop or a train. Perhaps, "[he] flung himself off [of the ledge]."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I find the use of the reflexive pronoun ***himself*** important. It doesn't say ***flung off*** (which is a transitive verb by the way, you can *[fling your clothes off](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/fling-off)*), but ***flung himself off***.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fling) says about ***fling***:

> If you *fling a part of your body* in a particular direction, especially your arms or head, you move it there suddenly.

The use of *himself* suggests that the person *moved his whole body away suddenly*. It is an informal, slightly humorous way of saying that ***he disappeared with a grin***. From where, where to and with what consequences can only be imagined without more context.